# Strange height value in the SDL_VIDEORESIZE event

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, sdl, gnome

I'm trying to create an application with the SDL, and would like the window to be resized.

For now, if I try to maximize the window, it works, if I place it in the left or right half of the screen, it works and take the right size.
But, when I resize the window by dragging one of it sides (vertical or horizontal), something really strange happen : the height grow until it's equal to the height of the screen.

When it grows, I can see that it's not instantaneous, in fact it takes many times times, growing each time of 37 pixels.
It's really strange, and I really don't know what to do.

I created a minimalist code to test if the problem was due to something special in my code, but it doesn't change anything, the problem is still the same.

Here is my minimalist code :

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Surface* surface=SDL_SetVideoMode(100, 100, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_RESIZABLE);
    SDL_Event event;

    while (true)
    {
        SDL_Flip(surface);
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        if (event.type==SDL_QUIT) break;
        else if (event.type==SDL_VIDEORESIZE)
        {
            surface=SDL_SetVideoMode(event.resize.w, event.resize.h, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_RESIZABLE);
        }
        SDL_Delay(30);
    }
}
```

So the problem don't seem to be in my code. (To verify that, I installed a game that use the SDL (Briquolo), and it has the same problem)

I searched on the web, but it seems that I'm the only person who got this problem (or it's maybe that I don't use the good keywords), so it seems that it's not the SDL.

The problem is probably caused by my system.
For information, got Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit, with the Gnome desktop.

How can I solve this problem, without having side effects ?

Comment: Please do not make edits to your question that invalidate existing answers.

Comment: I just though that it would be better to have a code that work the better possible, so that that it's clear that the bug don't come from this (or come from a specific part)

Comment: Cannot reproduce (with first edit's code - second one have FreeSurface which is obviously wrong), nor I truly understand the problem. Can you describe it better, and check with different window manager, preverable non-compositing one?

Comment: @keltar Why should the FreeSurface be wrong ? and what do you mean with "check different window manager" ?

Comment: @dido22 because [documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetVideoMode) says "The returned surface is freed by SDL_Quit and must not be freed by the caller. This rule also includes consecutive calls to SDL_SetVideoMode". As for WM, your gnome session probably uses compositing WM; there are several non-compositing ones, like `openbox`. Search articles concerning your desktop environment and distribution.

Comment: @keltar I search on the web about compositing and non-compositing window managers. If I understood well, with a non-compositing WM, I can't have "effect" (like scaling, deformations, ...) on windows, and I use some extensions (for example to switch between windows) that use that kind of things. I would like to keep these things working and run my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to avoid this (but I don't really understand why the first way didn't work) :

If I store the new sizes, process all events, and then resize, it works. Here's the working code :

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
 SDL_Surface* surface=SDL_SetVideoMode(100, 100, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_RESIZABLE);
 SDL_Event event;

 bool resized=false;
 int newW, newH;

 while (true)
 {
  while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
  {
   if (event.type==SDL_QUIT) return 0;
   else if (event.type==SDL_VIDEORESIZE)
   {
    resized=true;
    newW=event.resize.w;
    newH=event.resize.h;
   }
  }
 }
 if (resized)
 {
  resized=false;
  surface=SDL_SetVideoMode(newW, newH, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_RESIZABLE);
 }
 SDL_Flip(surface);
}
```

Comment: The call to SDL_SetVideoMode() is not in the outer loop, so it never gets called. I don't think this is a fix for the issue.